# How to parse XML via a template?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

**Background**:

I have large XML files (5-20 GB) consisting of a header record, and then a series of records with the same tag (but varying contents):

```
<header>
(...)
</header>
<host>
  <tagA>hello</tagA>
  <tagB name="world"></tagB>
  <tagC>bonjour</tagC>
</host>
<host>
  (...)
</host>
(...)
```

- when a tag in `<host>` exists, it always has the same structure.
- I am only interested in some tags contents (e.g. `hello` from `<tagA>`) and some tags' parameters (e.g. `world` from the parameter `name` of `<tagB>`). I discard other tags and content.

**How I deal with the files today**:

I read the input file, extract one by one the segments between `<host>` and `</host>` (including these boundary tags) and analyze them with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). This works fine, I get the elements I need.

**What I would like to do**:

I would however prefer to use a description of the analyzed `<host>` entry (some kind of schema) and state which elements are of interest to me.

I found many examples of the inverse exercise (how to create an XML file based on a template) but not of a schema-based analysis. Is such a method available?

Comment: Wouldn't adding a [mcve] help?

Comment: @boardrider: not sure what you are missing? You can find a sample of the data I analyse and I am not looking for a solution to some code which is not working (it is) but advice on approaching the problem differently (via a template /scheme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would approach the problem:

- Use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse the fragments, since they are proper XML.
- [Use `XPath`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) to describe and later extract the specific nodes. XPaths, being strings, are easy to store in a non-executable configuration storage.

It is not exactly 'template-based', but is definitely much more declarative and concise than raw Python code.